# Formula to rank data in a new table from another one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of transactions by industries (industrias) for 2 years (2017 and 2018) and from them I want to create another table in which only appear the first 4 industries that have more transactions (name of the industry and next to the number of transactions) and in a 5th row appear Other industries which add the number of transactions of the industries that were out of the ranking. (that is, the sum of all the other industries that did not reach the ranking). If there are industries that have the same amount I just need to sort them alphabetically.
What would be the formula for the "otras industrias" in the output? because it have to has the sum of the all other ones that are not in the top of the ranking.

**INPUT:**

```
Industrias                                  2017    2018
Acero, metalurgia y producción industrial    2       5
Aeroespacio y Aeronautica                    3       2
Agro                                         5       3
Agua y sanitización                          6       0 
Alimentos y bebidas                          7       0
Armas y Municiones                           8       6
Automotriz                                   4       6
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
Ranking 2018
       Industry       N° transacctions
1°  Name of industry          x
2°  Name of industry          Y
3°  Name of industry          Z
4° Otras industrias           w
```

Comment: Use the large() function and an offset() to get the name

Comment: Ore use `RANK()` from which a simple `INDEX` and `MATCH` will do the job...

Comment: @WaldenSch what is the desired output if 2 industires are having the same rank?

Comment: @p._phidot_ To sort them alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

For "Industry", this will handle ties since you're ranking integers:

`=INDEX(INPUT[Industrias],ROUND(MOD(1-LARGE(INDEX(INPUT[2018]+(ROW($C$2)-ROW(INPUT[2018]))/(COUNT(INPUT[2018])+1),),[@Rank]),1)*(COUNT(INPUT[2018])+1)+1,0),)`

Number of transactions will be simply:

`=LARGE(INPUT[2018],[@Rank])`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I can work out is..

1. highlight all your data(including headers),
2. Data > sort.
3. Then tick "my data has headers",
4. sort by > "2018", Order > "Largest" to smallest.
5. Add Level : sort by > "Industrias", Order > "A to Z" to smallest.

Done. Hope that solves. ( :

p/s : alternatively.. you may explore to build on formula using [manual text sort](https://chandoo.org/wp/sorting-text-in-excel-using-formulas/) .